# how to convert text to word embeddings using bert's pretrained model 'faster'?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I'm trying to get word embeddings for clinical data using microsoft/pubmedbert. I have 3.6 million text rows. Converting texts to vectors for 10k rows takes around 30 minutes. So for 3.6 million rows, it would take around - 180 hours(8days approx).

> Is there any method where I can speed up the process?

My code -

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline
model_name = "microsoft/BiomedNLP-PubMedBERT-base-uncased-abstract-fulltext"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
classifier = pipeline('feature-extraction',model=model_name, tokenizer=tokenizer)

def lambda_func(row):
    tokens = tokenizer(row['notetext'])
    if len(tokens['input_ids'])>512:
        tokens = re.split(r'\b', row['notetext'])
        tokens= [t for t in tokens if len(t) > 0 ]
        row['notetext'] = ''.join(tokens[:512])
    row['vectors'] = classifier(row['notetext'])[0][0]        
    return row

def process(progress_notes):     
    progress_notes = progress_notes.apply(lambda_func, axis=1)
    return progress_notes

progress_notes = process(progress_notes)
vectors_breadth = 768
vectors_length = len(progress_notes)
vectors_2d = np.reshape(progress_notes['vectors'].to_list(), (vectors_length, vectors_breadth))
vectors_df = pd.DataFrame(vectors_2d)
```

My progress_notes dataframe looks like -

```
progress_notes = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'progressnotetype':['Nursing Note', 'Nursing Note', 'Administration Note'], 'notetext': ['Patient\'s skin is grossly intact with exception of skin tear to r inner elbow and r lateral lower leg','Patient with history of Afib with RVR. Patient is incontinent of bowel and bladder.','Give 2 tablet by mouth every 4 hours as needed for Mild to moderate Pain Not to exceed 3 grams in 24 hours']})
```

> Note - 1) I'm running the code on aws ec2 instance r5.8x large(32
> CPUs) - I tried using multiprocessing but the code goes into a
> deadlock because bert takes all my cpu cores.

Comment: What about vectors_length and vectors_breadth? These values are undefined.

Comment: @LydiavanDyke - hello lydia, I have added the code which explains vectors_length and vectors_breadth

Comment: will the code become fast if I use GPU/TPU?

Answer (score 0):

isn't just ? apply is not the fastest method.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
sbert_model = SentenceTransformer('microsoft/BiomedNLP-PubMedBERT-base-uncased-abstract-fulltext')
document_embeddings = sbert_model.encode(pd.Series(['hello', 'cell type', 'protein']))
document_embeddings
```

you will get an output like

```
array([[ 0.06255245,  0.14945783, -0.06224129, ..., -0.11892398,
        -0.0507343 ,  0.0153866 ],
       [-0.17571464,  0.03554079, -0.04899959, ..., -0.24369009,
        -0.00672011,  0.04914075],
       [-0.22093703, -0.03271236, -0.08943298, ..., -0.21335356,
         0.11418738, -0.09207606]], dtype=float32)
```